# Bash Script to delete oldest files but keep latest files including sub-directories

Tags: shell, ls, rm, xargs

I'm trying to delete old files but should keep latest 3 days log files.i tried below command,

ls -tr /home/httpd/htdocs/pathname/pathname/config/*/build/logs/apps/*.log | tail -n +4 | xargs rm --

but it was deleted all files retain only 3 files one folder.but i want to remain 3 files every folders separately.

can anyone help me to solve this issue.

Comment: About parsing `ls`: [don't](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Unfortunately there is no straightforward *parsable* alternative for `ls -t` (at least I don't know any).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this, put the following content into a shell script file and execute it.

```
#!/bin/bash
dirs=($(find /tmp/test -type d))
for dir in "${dirs[@]}"; do
  cd "$dir"
  ls -pt | grep -v / | tail -n +4 | xargs rm -f
done
```

replace `/tmp/test` with your directory name.

Comment: This is worked for me. Thank you Lane :)

Answer (score 3):

You could use this command:

```
ls -t path | sed -e '1,3d' | xargs -d '\n' rm
```

Or in a loop:

```
for d in $(find path -type d); do
  ls -t "$d" | sed -e '1,3d' | xargs -d '\n' rm
done
```

Where:

- `ls -t` : lists files in decreasing order of modification time,
  one file name per line.
- `sed -e '1,3d'` : deletes the first 3 lines
- `xargs -d '\n' rm` : for each input line (without the terminating newline),
  passes it as an argument to `rm`.
- `-d '\n'` : this is needed for efficiency, to make xargs consider each input line
  a separate argument, yet pass as many arguments as will fit on a command line at once,
  so rm is not re-invoked for each one.

For more possibilities, see the post
[Delete all but the most recent X files in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25785/delete-all-but-the-most-recent-x-files-in-bash).

Comment: Yes Kamil its true,i want to keep three files per directory.in my case this doesn't ring any bell.btw thank you for your time.

Comment: You need to enclose the above in a loop. Something like: `for d in $(find path -type d); do above-command-using $d; done`

Comment: `for d in $(find path -type d); do` is [Bash pitfall number 1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29)

Comment: the thing is want keep latest 3 files per every directory(folders).not the recent 3 days files.other problem is there are several folders on my given path.

Comment: You might want `for file in path/*; do` and next line `[ -f "$file" ] || continue`. See [File test operators](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html).

Comment: And yes, this keeps the latest 3 files.